# StanfordNLP Model files throwing error

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

When i try to include the StanfordNLP Serialized Classifier File, it gives me the following exception.

```
edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Resource or file looks like a gzip file, but is not: models/ner/default/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

Can anybody help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first question is whether this report is simply correct....

Does this file exist in your file system or is it in a jar file in your classpath? If the latter, expand the jar file with the `jar -xf` command into a temporary directory to examine its contents.

Then examine this file. On Linux/macOS you could just use the `file` command. Otherwise you could use a program for examining/expanding compressed files. Is it a valid gzip-compressed file? For example, does the `file` command report:
`gzip compressed data`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what the problem was.

In my maven plugin "maven-resources-plugin", the "copy-resources" goal had "filtering" set to true. This corrupts the gz files.

Once removed, the above error stopped coming.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fuound what the problem was.

Maven plugin has a 'filtered' property which when set to true meddles with the gz files. That was screwing files. It works now.